# Unit Test Startup.cs

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, startup

I have some problems trying to do unit test with the Startup.cs file. I have no idea how to do it without integration test. There is any way to do it? I leave this part of code that I would like to have in my unit test. Im using xUnit

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: `Startup` is not something you'd unit test. It doesn't honestly *do* anything. You're simply adding services to `IServiceCollection` and adding middleware to the request pipeline, both of which the effects of can be seen only on a *running* app.

Answer (score 2):

You should isolate the functions you want to test.

For example, if you use special configurations like this pseudo code, you can test it by first splitting it up:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.AddFoo();
}

public void AddFoo(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    //stuff happens here
    //and you can test this.
}
```

Sometimes it can be hard because most of them are extension methods. But normally you can `Verify` if a specific function is being called.

If you have a tool like `.net Peek` you can actually see which non extension method is being called and verify that one.

If you are trying to "unit"-test the whole `startup.cs`, that's going to be hard, since the actual configuration is in there.

---

If you really want to test the whole flow, you must provide settings to be able to cope with the test run. You can create a custom webbuilder and call it with an actual client, but it's going to take a couple of extra if/else statements and it wont be pretty. We use a `startup.cs` which have some virtuals, so we can overload the tricky part and give it a custom implementation just for testing. To create such a setup, you can use this example:

```
private TestServer InitTestServer(HttpClient mockedHttpClient)
{
    var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseContentRoot(newBasePath)
        .UseEnvironment("UnitTest")
        .UseConfiguration(Configuration)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureTestServices((services) =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpClientFactory>(new CustomHttpClientFactory(mockedHttpClient));

            //some configuration override
        });

    return new TestServer(builder);
}
```

Comment: Yeap, im trying to unit test the whole startup.cs, but i have that part of the code and i was trying at least to unit test that. That code isnt mine, but i dont want to Exclude startup.cs from code coverage

Comment: Yes, so you should split it in the parts you can test, or, create an overridable startup cs... I added an example with test server.